# What vacuum should be defined for a observer in Kerr spacetime?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, vacuum, qft-in-curved-spacetime, kerr-metric

A scalar field in Kerr spacetime can have two kinds of modes, one labeled by "in", and the other by "up". The "in" modes originate from the past null infinity, while the "up" modes originate from the past horizon.

1. **The Boulware vacuum state** is defined by requiring that there are no "in" modes and "up" modes, i.e., no particles coming from the past null infinity and past horizon.
2. **The Unruh vacuum state** is defined by requiring that the "in" modes are empty while the "up" modes are thermally populated.
3. **The CCH vacuum state** is defined by requiring that the "in" and "up" modes are thermalized with respect to their natural energy.

These are past vacuum states; the future vacuum states can be defined similarly.

However, I do not know which vacuum state is appropriate for a specific observer. For example, if an observer is located far from the Kerr BH, what vacuum will be detected? What if the observer is locally static near the BH horizon, or the observer follows a stationary trajectory near the horizon?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the physical situation, not on the observer. Let me give three examples. I will focus on the analogy with Schwarzschild spacetime, which has the Boulware and Unruh vacua, but the Hartle–Hawking vacuum instead of the CCH vacuum because I am more familiar with it. Up to details pertaining to the CCH vacuum, the discussion should be the same though. You can also read a discussion on my master's thesis, available on [arXiv: 2305.17453 [gr-qc]](https://arxiv.org/abs/2305.17453). See the end of Sec. 2.4.

Firstly, suppose you are interested in an eternal black hole. In this case, the only Hadamard (i.e., renormalizable) stationary state in Schwarzschild spacetime is the Hartle–Hawking state. I believe the CCH vacuum must be a sort of analog of the Hartle–Hawking state for the Kerr black hole, but I believe it can't be Hadamard everywhere. Perhaps it is renormalizable only on a certain region, but not on the whole spacetime. Anyway, this is a vacuum adequate for an eternal black hole.

Suppose now you have a black hole created from stellar collapse. Then there is no past event horizon, but the Hartle–Hawking vacuum has modes coming up from the past horizon. Hence, since the past horizon does not exist, the Hartle–Hawking vacuum is not physical. However, the Unruh vacuum is Hadamard in the physical region (it is not Hadamard in the past horizon, which does not exist here), and hence it is the adequate vacuum.

Finally, suppose you have a spinning star with the outer metric being the Kerr metric. In this case, there are no event horizons, and hence the infalling modes given by the Unruh vacuum and by the Hartle–Hawking vacuum are unphysical. It remains to employ the Boulware vacuum (which fails to be Hadamard on the horizons, which do not exist now).

In all of these cases, the vacuum applies to all observers. A quantum state is a global construction. At best, you can say that near the future event horizon, the Hartle–Hawking and Unruh vacua approximate each other.